# A generalization of Young's inequality for convolutions?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

The Young's inequality for convolutions states that
$\|f \ast g\|_r \leq \|f\|_p\|g\|_q$ whenever $\frac{1}{r}+1=\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}$ and $p,q,r \geq 1$. There is also a reverse inequality when  $p,q,r \leq 1$.

My question is: could Young's inequality be true (probably under some additional assumptions for the functions involved) when two of the  numbers $p,q,r$ are $\geq 1$ and the the third one is $\leq 1$. In particular, I'm interested in the case when $r=1$,  $p>1$ and $q<1$.

Comment: Yes, consider $q=\frac{p}{2p-1}$. As an example we have $p=2$ and $q=2/3$.

Comment: Certainly there exist triples $p, q, r$ with these properties, the problem is that all proofs of Young's inequality I have looked at require that all $p,q,r \geq 1$.